# Blob detection + foreground detection

Tags: python, opencv

My frame differencing (foreground detection) works perfectly. Now, I want to add an extra function into it which is blob detection. Basically, my idea is to form blob circle on the detected object's motion.

This is my code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('14.mp4')
ret, current_frame = cap.read()
previous_frame = current_frame

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change blob detection thresholds
params.minThreshold = 200
params.maxThreshold = 255

params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 100

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 1200
params.maxArea = 40000

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = False
params.minCircularity = 0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = False
params.minConvexity = 0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.02

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

#Detect blobs
keypoints = detector.detect(current_frame)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    current_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    previous_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(previous_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    

    frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(current_frame_gray,previous_frame_gray)

    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(frame_diff, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    cv2.imshow('frame diff ',im_with_keypoints )         
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    previous_frame = current_frame.copy()
    ret, current_frame = cap.read()
    keypoints = detector.detect(current_frame)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My error is "image is not a numpy arrary, neither a scalar"

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `cap` variable to the function [`detector.detect`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?highlight=detect#featuredetector-detect), but `cap` comes from [`cv2.VideoCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) which returns a CvCapture object, not a Numpy array.

Instead, you should use the `current_frame` returned by `.read()`.

```
keypoints = detector.detect(current_frame)
```

Comment: Yes. I fixed it. But why the red circle not tracking the moving object. It just remain static at one point of the video.

Comment: @LeeAndroid Did you try to add `keypoints = detector.detect(current_frame)` also at the end of the loop, so blob detection can be refreshed at each new video frame?

Comment: Yes i did. I still cant find the bug. Even i added the code at the end of the loop. Still the same.

Comment: @LeeAndroid Sorry, I do not see why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should import library "numpy"

You can istall it, on your cmd(win+R , cmd , enter): pip install numpy

And write in your code: import numpy as np

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by your threshold parameters, mostly `params.minThreshold = 100` and `params.maxThreshold = 255`. Why did you set those specific values? Try tweeking them until you get good results.

On a side note, you don't seem to get this error but I was getting a cv2.error when running your code on one of my .avi videos. I fixed it by changing `while(cap.isOpened()):` to `while(ret)`.